# Where is list of Geographic Transformations in ArcGIS, and their areas of applicability?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, datum, list

I have some data in Provisional South American Datum 1956, and I need to project it to Web Mercator with WGS84 as the datum.

When I use the project tool in ArcGIS desktop, it requires a Geographic Transformation, and offers me 13 different ones: from `PSAD_1956_to_WGS_1984_1` to `PSAD_1956_to_WGS_1984_13`

How do I find out which is the transformation meant for my area?

I remember finding a pdf on the Esri Forums  several years ago, which showed the various transformations between NAD 83/27 & WGS 84.

Is there something similar for all transformations in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an excellent blog post on this topic here: [About geographic transformations and how to choose the right one](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/05/06/about-geographic-transformations-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/)

You can find the list of all transformations and their Areas of use, at the bottom of this ESRI Knowledge Base article: [HowTo:  Select the correct geographic (datum) transformation when projecting between datums](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21327)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Documentation folder in the ArcGIS Desktop installation folder. There is a file named geographic_transformations.pdf, here you can find ArcGIS 10.1 Geographic and Vertical Transformation Tables.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\Documentation\geographic_transformations.pdf