# Why do points shift when reprojected from WGS84 to a state plane coordinate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, gps

We have a Trimble GPS unit we use to collect system assets.

We collect the data in WGS84 and differentially correct it, and then reproject it into our State Plane Coordinate System.

The resulting points always shift the same distance in the same direction after the reprojection.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Are you applying the appropriate transformation?

Comment: The default transformations are not the best one. Select the one meant for your area. Here is how you find which is the best one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57026/where-can-i-get-the-list-of-geographic-tranformations-in-arcgis-and-the-area-whe

Comment: Which state plane coord system?

Comment: Can you perhaps specify which State Plane Coordinate System you are using and include a screenshot of the Transformation that you chose to use with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a lack of datum transformation in your projection operation.

Your symptom sounds familiar. It is a common problem here in Wisconsin - GPS uses the WGS84 datum, but our state system uses NAD83HARN.

The symptom of doing a projection without datum transformation is that coordinates are systematically offset a few meters in X and ~meter in Y.